# Read missing Word template from Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com-interop, office-interop

I have a series of Word documents which link to templates which no longer exist. This is causing problems for users trying to open them. I can get a list of the documents, loop through each one, and set the tempalte to null. While this will solve the problem, I can't determine what the template was before I changed it.

In cases where the template is not available on open, Word will replace the attached template with Normal.dot(x). However, the template I'm trying find is located in the document's Tempaltes dialog. Both AttachedTempalte() and get_AttachedTemplate().Name return Normal.dot when I know the document in question has a different template listed in the Templates dialog in word.

I can access this in VBA, and it's fustrating to not be able to do this in PS. Can anyone see where I'm messing up?

```
$word = new-object -comobject "Word.Application"
$doc = $word.Documents.Open({document path})
$word.Dialogs(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template()
```

Returns:

```
Missing ')' in method call.
At :line:1 char:15
+ $word.Dialogs(M <<<< icrosoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template()
```

Working VBA:

```
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim strTemplate as String
Set doc = Documents.Open(Filename:=filename, Visible:=False)
doc.Activate
strTemplate = Word.Dialogs(wdDialogsToolsTemplates).Template
```

After which I can see the template name and path I should see in strTemplate.

I checked the ps script and adding $doc.Activate doesn't seem to help. I also noticed that the interop and VBA do not use the same wdDialog. PS uses wdDialogToolsTemplates and VBA using wdDialogsToolsTemplates. I checked the assembly in PS with the following

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word") | out-null
[Enum]::GetNames("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDialogs")
```

and confirmed the correct option is wdDialogToolsTemplates.

Comment: Might help to see the VBA code that works.

Comment: I can replicate it, but not sure how to get around it. I'll keep poking at it as time permits, but a little busy today.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell you must use the [] brackets to specify types and then the :: to specify the type member, so your 3rd line of powershell code should look like this:

```
$word.Dialogs([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog]::wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template()
```

See these blog posts about powershell enums: [Jeffrey Snover](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/14/what-the-heck-is-an-enum.aspx) or [Richard Siddaway](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2011/08/02/enums.aspx).

Comment: Read the posts, thanks. The suggested command returns error: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplciationClass] doesn't contain a method named 'Dialogs'

Comment: If this was VBA, I would create a variable of the Dialogs type, set the dialog to wdDialogsToolsTempaltes, and return the Tempate property of the Dialogs object. I'm not sure if it's possible to do something in PS, or how to do that if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar and the main aim is not to store any code inside a Word document.

**PowerShell**

I made a tiny bit of progress with the PowerShell route but I can't find a way to extract the path from the dialog boxes.

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$objWord.Visible = $True
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\path\to\document.doc")
$objToolsTemplates = $objWord.Dialogs.Item([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog]::wdDialogToolsTemplates)
$objDocStats = $objWord.Dialogs.Item([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWordDialog]::wdDialogDocumentStatistics)
```

Now `$objToolsTemplates.Show()` and `$objToolsTemplates.Show()` both cause the GUI to display dialogs containing the path to the original (unavailable) template but I can't find any way to extract that information programatically. According to [MSDN WdWordDialog Enumeration documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdworddialog(v=office.14).aspx) both of the dialogs should have a `Template` property.

**VBScript**

In the end I had to go with VBS instead. The following code will give you the path of the original (unavailable) template. It's still a script at least.

```
Option Explicit

Const wdDialogToolsTemplates = 87
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0

Dim objWordApp
Dim objDoc
Dim dlgTemplate

Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWordApp.Visible = False
Set objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\path\to\document.doc")
Set dlgTemplate = objWordApp.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsTemplates)

Wscript.Echo dlgTemplate.Template

objDoc.Close(wdDoNotSaveChanges)
objWordApp.Quit
```